# Java generics both methods have same erasure error

Tags: java, generics

In my project, I have multiple services performing three basic operations - create, edit and search. For this, I am trying to create a generic service. Below is what I have come up with so far.

Search method will take a list of objects at runtime.

```
public interface GenericService<T> {

   void update(T t);

   void create(T t);

   T search(List<?> t);
}
```

Also, I have created an abstract class where the common code for all services will be placed.

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T> implements GenericService<T> {


}
```

Here is my implementation

```
public class AccountService extends AbstractService<Account> implements GenericService<Account> {
    @Override
    public void update(Account account) { }

    @Override
    public void create(Account account) { }

    @Override
    public Account search(List<SearchCriteria> t) { return null; }
}
```

Here are my Account and SearchCriteria classes

```
public class Account {
    private String accountNumber;
    private Date openingDate;
    // more fields
    // getter setter removed for brevity
}
```

Search criteria class

```
 public class SearchCriteria {
        private String key;
        private String value;
        // getter setter removed for brevity
    }
```

**Problem:** on line public Account search(List t) { return null; }, getting compilation error saying

> 'search(List)' in
>   'com.test.AccountService' clashes with
>   'search(List)' in 'com.test.GenericService';
>   both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Comment: Change `List<?>` in `search` in the interface to `List<T>`.

Comment: @Schred - I tried that as well - it gives following compilation error:

'search(List<SearchCriteria>)' in 'com.optidesk.core.service.test.AccountService' clashes with 'search(List<T>)' in 'com.optidesk.core.service.test.GenericService'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Comment: Can your search method really take a list of anything, can't you use SearchCriteria in your interface definition?

Comment: Yes, it can take a list of anything. I really need to understand why the compilation fails with the current implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for

```
public Account search(List<SearchCriteria> t) { ...}
```

to override

```
T search(List<?> t);
```

The arguments must be the same after type parameter substitution, but `?` is not `SearchCriteria`.

Therefore, if you want to keep these methods (the inheritance looks a bit wild to me), you'll need to parameterise the types further.

```
public interface GenericService<T, C> {
   // ...
   T search(List<C> t); // probably change that parameter name
}

public abstract class AbstractService<T, C>
        implements GenericService<T, C>
{
}

public class AccountService
        extends AbstractService<Account, SearchCriteria>
        implements GenericService<Account, SearchCriteria> // unnecessary
{
    // ...
    @Override
    public Account search(List<SearchCriteria> t) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `List<?>` to `List<SearchCriteria>` in `GenericService` will solve the error. There is no benefit in using a wildcard if the `search` method will always take a list of `SearchCriteria` objects in every service implementation.

If, however, you want to make this generic as well, you can introduce a second type parameter.